# Removing hours from time

Tags: php, mysqli

My goal: **Remove 4 hours from the time in the database and then run code to send a text. In the process, remove seconds and only go off the basis of hours and minutes.** The seconds are removed in the PHP part and displayed but not removed in the database(would be handy if someone could teach me this part also to only display hours and minutes, and remove seconds from the DB)

I currently have:

```
#Variables
$Time = Time in the DB


$TimeMinus = strtotime('- 4 hours');

$TimeNow = date("h:i:sa");

$cleantime = substr($Time,0,5);
```

I then tried to run the following:

```
$TimeRemoved = substr($TimeNow,0,5) - $TimeMinus;
```

and debug it via

```
echo "Current time: $TimeNow<br>Time in DB: $cleantime<br/>Time with four hours removed: $TimeRemoved.";
```

but i get this response:

```
Current time: 05:55:09pm
Time in DB: 17:40
Time with four hours removed: -1536580504.
```

The time with four hours removed displays weirdly. I'm not the best in mysqli or php so excuse the coding.

Comment: I have changed the $TimeRemoved code to:

$TimeRemoved = substr($Time,0,5) - 4;

and now it displays "13." Of course, this is correct, but it doesn't display the minutes.

Comment: It seems to work as expected. Strtotime(-4 hours) will give you 'now' - 4 hours in Unix time (seconds that has elapsed since 1970). When you remove that from your time own that is a string it will return a negative value

Comment: Focus your question more on what you have and what you want, it's a bit confusing to read. Include sample input and what it's supposed to look like after the code has run

Answer (score 0):

For a MySQL based solution, you may use the `TIME_FORMAT` function, with a format mask containing only hours and minutes.  For example:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('15:02:28', '%H:%i')
FROM dual;

15:02
```

Answer (score 0):

`$time4=strtotime($sqltime - 14400); // your sqltime minus 4 hours
$cleantime = date( 'G:i', $time4);`

Where sqltime is the datetime you get from your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn it into timestamp first, then change it.

I'm not sure what exactly you need, then I will show you a bunch of results:

```
$times = [];

$times["db"] = strtotime($Time);
$times["now"] = time();
$times["removed"] = strtotime('- 4 hours');
$times["removedFromDB"] = $times["db"] - 60 * 4;

foreach ($times as $key => $time) {
    echo $key . " - " . date("H:i", $time) . " | ";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/lEGF7